# Unicode in shell script to github API

Tags: bash, shell, github, github-api

I am trying to create labels using github api, but pass in emojis to the label name. Any ideas on how I can do this properly?

```
source config.txt

labels2=(
    "Sleep $zzz_unicode:FFFFFF"
)

# Read repository names from file
while IFS= read -r repo; do
    REPO_USER=$(echo "$repo" | cut -f1 -d /)
    REPO_NAME=$(echo "$repo" | cut -f2 -d /)

    echo "-----------------------------------------[$REPO_USER/$REPO_NAME]---------------------------------"

    # Iterate over labels
    for label in "${labels2[@]}"; do
        label_name=$(echo "$label" | cut -d ":" -f 1)
        label_color=$(echo "$label" | cut -d ":" -f 2)


        data="{\"name\":\"$label_name $emoji\",\"color\":\"$label_color\"}"
        response=$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}" -u "$token:x-oauth-basic" --request POST --data "$data" "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO_USER/$REPO_NAME/labels")
        response_code=$(echo "$response" | tail -n1)
        response_body=$(echo "$response" | sed '$d')
        if [[ $response_code -eq 201 ]]; then
            echo "Label '$label_name $emoji' created successfully in repository '$REPO_USER/$REPO_NAME'"
        else
            echo "Failed to create label '$label_name $emoji' in repository '$REPO_USER/$REPO_NAME'. Response: $response_body"
        fi
    done

done < repo_names.txt
```

Tried using github unicode, as well as the actual emoji in label creation:

`"Bug :FF0000"`

`"Sleep $zzz_unicode:FFFFFF"`

I created a label manually on a repo:
`Bug`  with color `FF0000`. I can run a script to return all labels for that repo:

```
Fetching labels for Repo...
[
  {
    "id": someID,
    "node_id": "some_nodeID",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/repo/labels/test%20%F0%9F%90%9B",
    "name": "test ",
    "color": "ff0000",
    "default": false,
    "description": ""
  }
]
```

But if I try using my script above to create the label for me using github API with the emoji in the label itself during creation: `"Bug :FF0000"` It creates label as`Bug ??`

If I try creation with unicode: `"Sleep $zzz_unicode:FFFFFF"` it creates label as `Sleep` Note that sleep is just a test - `zzz` is github zzz emoji  but should work the same.

Comment: What results are you expecting, and what are you getting? You told us you tried, but not what happened.

Comment: @MarkReed Thanks for feedback. I don't use stack too often. I updated my post with more clarification.

Comment: What encoding does your text file and your shell script use? We can’t tell you the correct encoding without seeing (a representative, ideally small sample of) the actual contents of the data in an unambiguous representation; a hex dump of the problematic byte(s) with a few bytes of context on each side is often enough, especially if you can tell us what you think those bytes are supposed to represent. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: Forgive me @tripleee. I am no expert in encoding. I've never used emojis before, and don't often do this. Way out of my comfort zone. Files, terminals all UTF-8, which is what github supports. All my code is in my post for the create_labels.sh file. If I should be encoding them somehow differently, please do enlighten me.

Comment: There aren't any emojis in your posted code. How are you setting, for example, `zzz_unicode`? If your script source is UTF-8, you should just be able to do e.g. `zzz_unicode=''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github requires that you use their naming convention when submitting a request. Here is an example of my lables I wanted to implement:

```
labels=(
    "Bug :bug::FF0000"           # 
    "Feature :sparkles::00FF00"          # ✨
    "Documentation :books::0000FF" # 
)
```

And then just ensuring you are extracting label components properly when making your request.

```
label_name=$(echo "$label" | cut -d ":" -f 1)
label_emoji=$(echo "$label" | grep -oP ':[^:]+:')
label_color=$(echo "$label" | grep -oP '::\K.*$')
```

Here is an overview:

````
for label in "${labels[@]}"; do
        # Extract label components
        label_name=$(echo "$label" | cut -d ":" -f 1)
        label_emoji=$(echo "$label" | grep -oP ':[^:]+:')
        label_color=$(echo "$label" | grep -oP '::\K.*$')

        # Construct the label text with emoji shortcode
        label_text="\"name\":\"$label_name $label_emoji\""
        label_color="\"color\":\"$label_color\""

        # Print label text and color
        echo "{ $label_text, $label_color }"

        # Ensure proper color format (remove leading '#')
        label_color=$(echo "$label_color" | sed 's/^#//')

        # Prepare data for the POST request
        data="{ $label_text, $label_color }"  # Ensure proper color format

        # Send POST request to create label
        response=$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}" -u "$token:x-oauth-basic" --request POST --data "$data" "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO_USER/$REPO_NAME/labels")
        response_code=$(echo "$response" | tail -n1)
        response_body=$(echo "$response" | sed '$d')
        if [[ $response_code -eq 201 ]]; then
            echo "Label '$label_name $label_emoji' created successfully in repository '$REPO_USER/$REPO_NAME'"
        else
            echo "Failed to create label '$label_name $label_emoji' in repository '$REPO_USER/$REPO_NAME'. Response: $response_body"
        fi
    done
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

If

1. all your scripts are encoded in UTF-8, and
2. your terminal supports it likewise, and
3. you're running a modern version of Bash

(and by "modern", I mainly mean *not* the version 3.2 that ships in `/bin` on macOS)

... then Unicode characters *should* mostly Just Work. Here's a simple demonstration of bash acting Unicode-friendly:

```
$ printf '%X\n' "'"
1F4A4
```

As you can see, it recognizes the emoji as a single character and displays its code point when requested.

But many UNIX tools – like `cut` – are not so safe for multibyte text. I don't see where in your code you're setting the `emoji` variable that you use, but if you're doing any kind of parsing to get it the way you're doing for the repo and label, it could be giving you invalid results for that reason.

It might help to stick to bash builtins. For example, instead of this:

```
REPO_USER=$(echo "$repo" | cut -f1 -d /)
REPO_NAME=$(echo "$repo" | cut -f2 -d /)
```

you could do do this:

```
IFS=/ read REPO_USER REPO_NAME _ <<<"$repo"
```

(Although I don't know why you're naming those vars in all-caps; they don't appear to be being set as environment variables.)

If you could supply the whole program (minus auth keys or other sensitive data, of course), it might help.

Comment: Re: uppercase variables, see also [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to figure it out. Github requires that you use their naming convention. See my post below.